# How to change 3rd Div backgroundColor using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 5 div. There is not ID or Class on it. I have to change background color of 3rd div. I try with below, please let me know what went wrong here.

```
 <div>Div sample content</div>
    <div>Div sample content</div>
    <div>Div sample content</div>
    <div>Div sample content</div>
    <div>Div sample content</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    <input type="button" onclick="getValue()" value="Click"/>

function getValue()
        {
            var result = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    alert(result.length);
            result[4].style.backgroundcolor ="red";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of the 3rd div use `result[2]` and the capitalize the `C` in `backgroundColor`

```js
function getValue()
        {
            var result = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    alert(result.length);
            result[2].style.backgroundColor ="red";
        }
```

```html
 <div>Div sample content</div>
    <div>Div sample content</div>
    <div>Div sample content</div>
    <div>Div sample content</div>
    <div>Div sample content</div>


    <input type="button" onclick="getValue()" value="Click"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result[2].style.backgroundColor ="red";
       ^-third            ^-capital
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jzzewees/)

Answer (score 0):

Try capitalizing the c in background*C*olor.